# Run an external Javascript in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I want to run a booking Javascript in a specific place of a page of my Wordpress site.

I added this code in a `functions.php`:

```
function your_scripts() 
{ 
  wp_register_script('script','http://www.website.it/includeMask.php?ID=MjgE4Yg&lang=it&maskType=hfmc&extType=js&modal=true',false);
  wp_enqueue_script('script');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'your_scripts');
```

I'm using a purchase template, and in the same page, where I will put this script, there is another default plugin of the template.
My Javascript appears in a header. How can I put the script in a specific place in the middle page - but avoid conflict with the other script?

Comment: Don't put a space between Java and Script if you mean Javascript...and don't tag Java either. Java and Javascript have no realation to each other.

Comment: Your code is working?

Comment: you can't put it in the middle of the page with those functions.

Comment: I'd suggest getting embed code and pasting that in a page or post on your Wordpress site via the post editor. You'll need to understand how wordpress hooks work, how wordpress enqueues scripts work (what you're doing), and then how to "get it into the middle of your page" in order to proceed with your method above. Pasting embed code in your page may be an easier method for someone starting out.